# i want to change the selected values and also update with using select and option with using react js

Tags: reactjs

In a React component for a  menu, I need to set the selected attribute on the option that reflects the state.

**i have an array, which has key and value,
whenever i select and change value from public to private than values are hit but nothing to change ..**

*here is my code..*

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      privacy: [
        {
          ratingVisiblity:'1',
          CompanyVisiblity:'1'
        }
      ]
    };
    this.onSelectHand = this.onSelectHand.bind(this);
  }

  onSelectHand = e => {

    this.setState({
      ...this.state.privacy,
      [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          {this.state.privacy.map((value, ind) =>
            Object.keys(value).map((key, indx) => (
              <>
                <span>{key}</span>

                <select
                  name={key}
                  value={this.state[key] || this.state[value[key]]}
                  onChange={this.onSelectHand}
                >
                  <option value="1"> public</option>
                  <option value="0">private</option>
                  <option value="2">Network</option>
                </select>
              </>
            ))
          )}
        </div>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.onSelectHand function may lost "this" point , try to bind this to your function :

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
        privacy:[{
        ratingVisiblity:'1',
        CompanyVisiblity:'1'
    }]
  }
  this.onSelectHand = this.onSelectHand.bind(this);
}
```

2. please return value from iterator object

```
    onSelectHand = (e, key) => {
      console.log([e.target.name] + ":" + e.target.value);
      console.info({ key });
      let result = this.state.privacy;
      result[0][key] = e.target.value;
      console.info({ result });
      this.setState(result);
    };
```

please refer : https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-mclaren-0x6ph?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I notice the result in function is undefined , you could see https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-mclaren-0x6ph?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark for check , i had edit the function and when you select option something will change , you could try this

Comment: but still state is not updating , i want to update state after select any option, for this i changed  the code,

Comment: i had change the code https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-mclaren-0x6ph?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark you can take a look, this might change option after select